# General method for constructing bitwise expressions satisfying constraints/with certain values?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

Say I'm looking for a bitwise function to have certain values, for instance -

```
f(0b00,0b00)!=0         
f(0b00,0b10)==0     
f(0b10,0b10)!=0     
f(0b11,0b10)!=0     
f(0b01,0b10)==0
```

Is there a general method for constructing a single bitwise expression f for such systems?  (I don't know for sure, but think there might be crappy solutions possible if you have gigantic expressions masking out one bit at a time, so let's say that the expressions have to work for all sizes of ints)

The best I've been able to do to convert the above is

```
f(int a, int b) 
{
    if (a==0    ) {
        return b==0;
    } else {
        return (a&b)!=0;
    }
}
```

I have a suspicion that it's difficult to combine (x==0) conditions with (x!=0) conditions (given x, is there a bitwise function f such that x==0 <=> f(x)!=0? ), but i don't know how much of an impediment that is here.

Any answers would be poured over with great interest :)

Peace,

S

Comment: The usual method for simplifying boolean algebra like this is the [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: Not sure if that's what I'm looking for - it deals with manipulating individual boolean variables rather than bit arrays. But it is interesting regardless. Thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: You can still use the same principle for bit arrays - it's just a big 2D truth table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general construction is an extended version of "minterms". Use bitwise operators to construct a predicate that is -1 iff the input matches a specific thing, AND the predicate with whatever you want the result to be, then OR all those things together. That leads to horrible expressions of course, possibly of exponential size.

Using arithmetic right shifts, you can construct a predicate `p(x, c) = x == c`:

```
p(x, c) = ~(((x ^ c) >> 31) | (-(x ^ c) >> 31))
```

Replace 31 by the size of an int minus one.

The only number such that it and its negation are both non-negative, is zero. So the thing inside the final complement is only zero if `x ^ c == 0`, which is the same as saying that `x == c`.

So in this example, you would have:

```
(p(a, 0x00) & p(b, 0x00)) |
(p(a, 0x10) & p(b, 0x10)) |
(p(a, 0x11) & p(b, 0x10))
```

Just expand it.. into something horrible.

Obviously this construction usually doesn't give you anything sensible. But it's general.

In the specific example, you could do:

```
f(a, b) = (p(a, 0) & p(b, 0)) | ~p(a & b, 0)
```

Which can be simplified a little again (obviously the xors go away if `c == 0`, and two complements balance each other out).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I hadn't heard of the term "minterm" before, it's interesting.  p seems to rely very crucially on the size of the int.  The example I gave can be written as f(a,b) =( (a&b)|!(a|b) ), and I'm not sure how I'd get that, if following your method.

Comment: @increpare you wouldn't get that, but personally I reject that as a truly bitwise solution anyway, because it uses the `!` operator. Anyway, like I said, this method is general, not efficient. To get an efficient solution, I really don't know any other method than "just think about it".

Comment: @increpare you can, of course, write `p` in terms of `!`, if you're OK with that, as `p(x, c) = -!(x ^ c)`.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct in rejecting it as a proper bitwise solution.  Thanks for the other formulation of P, it might come in handy in future.